# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: TITLE (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT TITLE, STORY FROM MY_TABLE

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm working on a simple application that contains short stories and I'm trying to use a database but I got an error:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: TITLE (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT TITLE, STORY FROM MY_TABLE

SQLiteActivity.java

```
package com.scriptos.testsqlit;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SQLiteActivity {
     private static String DBNAME = "Sqlite_simple.db";
     private static String TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
     private static String COLUMN_1 = "TITLE";
     private static String COLUMN_2 = "STORY";


    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private SQLiteOpenHelper helper_database;

    private Context context;

    public SQLiteActivity(Context c){
        context = c;
    }

    public SQLiteActivity Read() throws android.database.SQLException {
        helper_database = new SQLiteHelper(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
        database = helper_database.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public SQLiteActivity Write() throws android.database.SQLException {
        helper_database = new SQLiteHelper(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
        database = helper_database.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        helper_database.close();
    }

    public long insert(String title, String story){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_1, title);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_2, story);

        return database.insert(TABLE, null, contentValues);
    }

    public int deleteAll(){
        return database.delete(TABLE, null, null);
    }

    public String[] getAll(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2};
        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE, columns,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        String [] result = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int title = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_1);
        int story = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_2);

        int a = 0;
        for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()){
            result [a] =
                    cursor.getString(title) + "   " +
                     cursor.getString(story) ;
            a++;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                            SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS " + TABLE + " (ID INTEGER KEY, "+COLUMN_1+ "TEXT, "+COLUMN_2 +"TEXT);");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.scriptos.testsqlit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    SQLiteActivity db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        String[] adapter = new String[] { "a", "b", "c",};

        ArrayAdapter<String> i = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, adapter);

        listView.setAdapter(i);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://andrody.com/"));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://m.facebook.com/andrody2015"));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (position == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCAGUgnnL47fU3TMRhKhkQwQ"));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });


        db = new SQLiteActivity(this);
        db.Write();
        db.deleteAll();
        db.insert("title1", "story1");
        db.insert("title2","story2");
        db.insert("title3","story3");
        db.close();


        SHOW();
    }

    public void SHOW() {
        db.Read();
        String [] x = db.getAll();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff5ffcf">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

What should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your create table line;

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS " + TABLE + 
  " (ID INTEGER KEY, "+COLUMN_1+ "TEXT, "+COLUMN_2 +"TEXT);");
```

...generates the SQL...

```
CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS MY_TABLE (ID INTEGER KEY, TITLETEXT, STORYTEXT);
```

...which, due to missing spaces is not valid SQL and won't create the table.

Add the missing spaces to your create table, and it should work better.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS " + TABLE + 
  " (ID INTEGER KEY, "+COLUMN_1+ " TEXT, "+COLUMN_2 +" TEXT);");

CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS MY_TABLE (ID INTEGER KEY, TITLE TEXT, STORY TEXT);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think no space is there in your table creation

```
CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS " + TABLE + " (ID INTEGER KEY, "+COLUMN_1+"        
  TEXT, "+COLUMN_2 +"  TEXT);");
```

it may be better